# Как правильно сравнивать отрицательные числа?

Tags: c#, математика, compare

Есть метод, который вызывается каждый раз при действии.
Он имеет три параметра: объект с которым будем работать, число для работы, и bool который понимает будет ли число добавлено или вычтено.

```
void Filler(Object obj, int count, bool adds)
{
    int point = obj.point;
    int level = obj.level;
}
```

При каждом вызове я добавляю к **point** полученный **count**
когда **point** достигает 59 он должен обнулится а значение **level** получить себе +1
это работает если полученный **count** будет равен 1.
Но вот мне понадобилось больше, например **count** пришел со значением 200, вот здесь я и начинаю пересчет:

```
if (adds)
{
    if ((point + count) / 59 < 1) point += count;
    else {
        var raise = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Floor((double)(point + count) / 59.0));
        point = (point + count) - (raise * 59);
        level += raise;
    }
} else {
    if ((point - count) / 59 >= 0) point -= count;
    else {
        // point = (point - count) - 59;
        // level -= Convert.ToInt32(Math.Ceiling((double)(point + count) / 59.0));
    }
}
```

С добавлением все хорошо, а вот с вычетом не могу разобраться.
Моя проверка заходит в минусы и я не могу понять как это пресечь.
Я чего то пытался и по модулю делать проверку, но потом отбросил эту идею.
Дошел до того, что начал перебирать методом "тыка", то операторы сравнения менял, до пытался проверить что бы результат не был отрицательным, но все тщетно.

Comment: При добавлении все проще, по крайней мере для меня!
Нужно понять сколько уровней сразу добавить к level, а сам point обнулить и установить ему остаток.
Похоже на г*вно-код, но оно работает!
С отрицательным я думал точно так же, просто отнимать, но увы, что то я делаю не так(

Comment: `level += (point + count) / 59; point = (point + count)%59;`?

Comment: @tym32167
Это помогло проще добавлять уровни с поинтами.
А как отнять? Пробовал: `level -= (point + count) / 59; point = (point - count)%59;` но в таком случае point получает отрицательное значение, хоть и уровни отнимает верно.

Comment: не силен ес честно, но что если так: `point = (59 + point - count%59)%59;` ?

Comment: @tym32167 то же самое, может с проверкой что то не то? `if ((point - count) / 59 >= 0 && point > 0)`

Comment: оно не может быть то же самое. Выражение `(59 + point - count%59)%59` не может быть меньше 0 ни в каких случаях, если point и count сами по себе положительные числа

Comment: Я попробовал этот вариант: `(59 + point - count%59)%59` point так же уходит в минус.

Comment: это при каких значениях point и count выражение становится ниже нуля? Покажите код

Comment: Что должно происходить, когда идут минусы? Например, 40 и минус 50 — что должно произойти? как измениться point и level? А при 40 и 200? Просто покажите, что **должно быть**, и сразу станет понятно, что делать...

Comment: @Mikhailo ок! Вот пример: у меня 3 уровень и 40 поинтов, я делаю минус 50, значит уровень становится 2 а поинтов 10 (если отнимаю поинтов больше чем есть, то снимаю количество уровней, а остаток отнимаю от 59). Другой пример, те же 3 уровень и 40 поинтов, я делаю минус 200, в 200 будет аж три целых 59 и остаток 23, знач уровень надо сделать 0, а поинтов (40-23) 17.

Comment: Я кажись понял как поинты вычитать здесь правильно: `point = 59 - ((count - point)%59);`
и проверка вроде проще: `if (point >= count)`, короче если текущих поинтов больше или равно зашедшему count, то просто отнимаем count от point а иначе, находим разницу между count и point находим их остаток деления и отнимаем его от 59 это и должно быть поинт. По вашему примеру, посчитал вручную для 40 поинтов, минус 50 и 40 поинтов минус 200, вроде все правильно.
Появилась проблема с уровнями, он отнимает всегда на один уровень меньше чем надо, в случае если надо отнять всего один, то ничего не делает.